# WINE32 deleting files...... trying to install unsafe and harmful packages

Tags: 21.04

Please help I tried to install WINE from snap store and told me the package wine32 was missing so I installed that it said another package was missing....I installed that too....but it started deleting my file..it deleted the terminal too.
One thing I remember is that it asked me to enter '''Yes,do as I say'''

Comment: Were you following some instructions somewhere?  Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1352232/edit) your question and add in the exact commands that you used to try to install WINE?  The `"Yes, do as I say!"` is for your protection from apt trying to warn you that what you are doing can damage your installation by removing core programs that are needed.  Any more details that you can add to your question will greatly help us to help you solve your problem.  Thank you!

Comment: I don't have any other information but the problem is solved by reinstalling Ubuntu. Learnt a good lesson too.